# Frobenius number of a set of integers in an arithmetic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, diophantine-equations

Given positive integers $a, d, n$ with $gcd(a, d) = 1$, consider the Arithmetic Sequence

$a, a + d, a + 2d, \dots, a + nd$

Let $A$ be the set consisting this sequence.

The Frobenius number $g$, of this arithmetic sequence is given by the closed form formula:

$g = \lfloor { a - 2 \over n } \rfloor a + d(a - 1)$

The Frobenius number of the arithmetic sequence is the largest number that cannot be represented as a weighted sum of the members the sequence. The weights $w_i$ are positive integers and zero (i.e. $w_i \in W$, the set of whole numbers).

i.e., $g \ne \sum_{i} w_i x_i $, where $x_i \in A, w_i \in W$

The Frobenius number occurs in the [Frobenius Coin Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem). The formula above is also available in the same Wikipedia reference in section titled *Frobenius numbers for special sets*.

For every Arithmetic Sequence, there is a Frobenius number that can be computed using the formula given above.

I am looking at the converse. Given positive integer $g$, find the arithmetic sequence defined by $a, d, n$ such that $g$ is its Frobenius number with

- maximal $n$ i.e., the longest sequence (or)
- smallest $d$ (or)
- minimal $a + d$

(I don't know if one of these implies the other)

**Approach**

We know that the trivial two member arithmetic sequence $a, a+d$ always exists for any $g$. This is because we can always solve the linear Diophantine equation $aX + (a-1)Y = g$ using the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) as $gcd(a, a-1) = 1$. We also know that if a solution exists for $X, Y$, there are an infinite number of solutions. We can solve for $n$ by substituting $\lfloor { a - 2 \over n } \rfloor = X$ and $d = Y$.

So, we have an oracle that can give us $d, n$ dependent on $g, a$.

My heuristic approach is to use the given $g$ and choose various $a$ and then select the $a, d, n$ that meets the criteria. I know this does not give me the optimal solutions for any given $g$.

Is there a way to determine the optimal solution(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be an integer and let $(a,d,n)$ be an integral solution to
$$g=\left\lfloor\frac{a-2}{n}\right\rfloor a+d(a-1),\tag{1}$$
with $a,d,n>0$. First note that $d(a-1)\geq0$ and $\lfloor\tfrac{a-2}{n}\rfloor\geq-1$, with equality if and only if $a=1$ in both cases. It follows that no such integral solutions exist for $g\leq-1$. For $g=-1$ we must have $a=1$, and then any choice of $d$ and $n$ yields $g=-1$. Of course $g=0$ is impossible, so from here on we consider only the case where also $g$ is positive. Note that then $a>1$.

For every $g>0$ there is no maximum to the values that $n$ can take. After all, for $a=2$ and $d=g$ equation $(1)$ simplifies to $g=d$. In particular we see that there exists a solution for *every* positive integer $n$.

For every $g>0$ the minimal value of $d$ is $d=1$. For $d=1$ equation $(1)$ becomes
$$g=\left\lfloor\frac{a-2}{n}\right\rfloor a+a-1,$$
so taking any $n>a-2$ this further simplifies to $g=a-1$. So for every positice integer $c$ the triple
$$(a,d,n)=(g+1,1,g-1+c),$$
is a solution to $(1)$ with $d$ minimal. This shows that there is still no maximum to the values that $n$ can take.

Minimizing $a+d$ seems to be difficult, though. Here is a table of the minimal values $m$ of $a+d$ for small values of $g$:
$$\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrrrrrrrr}
g&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20\\
\hline
m&2&3&4&5&5&4&6&5&7&6&6&5&8&7&6&9&8&7&10&6&8\\
\end{array}$$
It does not seem to match anything in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).